# Display Audio Meters in Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, audio

Is there any way to display audio meters in the Video Sequence Editor?
I mean something like this:
[image]

Pretty much every NLE has one, but I'm unable to find one in Blender's VSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a built-in feature, but you can get an audio-meter in the VSE by installing this (essential) VSE add-on: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

[image]